# why does git checkout remember deleted branches

Tags: git, gitlab

`git checkout` ( then press Tab twice), shows a list of branches including already deleted ones.

Most of them are not exist in the list from `git branch -a`. They can not be removed by `git branch -D trash_branch`

How could I clean up the list remembered by `git chechout`?

Comment: Have you tried this git fetch --prune --all ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that the remote status it not reflected on the local git clone. You can prune the remotely deleted branches with:

```
git fetch -p
```

Then continue by deleting the local ones as you already described.

```
git branch -D <branch name>
```

To see the current status of branches compared to the remote, use this useful command: (thanks [Erik Schierboom](https://www.erikschierboom.com/2020/02/17/cleaning-up-local-git-branches-deleted-on-a-remote/))

```
git for-each-ref --format '%(refname:short) %(upstream:track)' refs/heads
```